# How can I convert an API endpoint into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api, python-requests

I have found this following API endpoint from binance which unfortunately doesn't have a documentation on their page. They are using it directly on their [website](https://www.binance.com/en/leveraged-tokens/tokens/allTokens) UI.

I have found the POST Request to the [https://www.binance.com/gateway-api/v1/public/future/leverage/token/basket/list](https://reqbin.com/e2igpbpp) actually works. The problem is I would like to convert this info into a dataframe.

I have tried the following, unfortunately, I cannot find a way to convert the following into dataframe as the type is not yet json.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

**My attempt:**

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "https://www.binance.com/gateway-api/v1/public/future/leverage/token/basket/list"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

data = """
{"asset": "BTCUP", "current": 1, "size": 20}

"""


resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(resp.content) #shows the data as class 'byte'
```

Comment: Try `resp.json()` instead

Comment: Ahhh I forgot the `()`last time, thank you!